# I cant format the output of this command correctly

Tags: python, powershell, text, formatting

Here is the command I am executing:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\*"  | Where-Object {$_."(default)" -ne $null} | Select-Object @{ expression={$_.PSChildName}; label='Program'} ,@{ expression={$q + $_."(default)" +$q}; label='CommandLine'}
```

Here is a snippet of the output:

```
Program                    CommandLine                                                                                                 
-------                    -----------                                                                                                 
7zFM.exe                   C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zFM.exe                                                                             
AcroRd32.exe               C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe                                          
Adobe Audition CC.exe      "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Audition CC 2019\Adobe Audition CC.exe"                                       
Adobe Media Encoder.exe    "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Media Encoder CC 2019\Adobe Media Encoder.exe"                                
Adobe Premiere Pro.exe     "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2019\Adobe Premiere Pro.exe"                                  
AfterFX.exe                C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects CC 2019\Support Files\AfterFX.exe                                
BJMYDGN.EXE                C:\Program Files\Canon\MyPrinter\BJMyDgn.exe                                                                
BJMYPRT.EXE                C:\Program Files\Canon\MyPrinter\BJMyPrt.exe
```

I'm new to text formatting, and I am trying to create this in a csv file, with 2 columns, Programs and Executables and removing all Quotation Marks "".  The $q + removes quotation marks, however if an item has 2 sets of quotation marks, one set remains as above (sorry I should have clarified that..

I think I am running in circles and just looking for some help.

I figured out the csv formatting by piping this:

```
| Export-Csv -Path .\programs.csv -Encoding ascii -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\*"  | Where "(default)" -ne $null | 
        Select @{ E={$_.PSChildName}; N='Program'} ,@{ E={$_."(default)".Trim('"')}; N='CommandLine'} |
            export-csv .\programs.csv -Encoding ascii -NoType
```

Comment: Thank you Esperento57 and Ryan, this bottom code worked.

Answer (score 0):

The string object in .NET has a [Trim()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.8) method that normally strips whitespace from the beginning and end of the string, but can also take an array of characters to strip as well.

So it should be good enough to modify your expression for CommandLine to this:

```
$_.'(default)'.Trim('"')
```

P.S. I'm not sure what the `$q` variable you have in the CommandLine expression is. But I don't think you need it.

Comment: When I change my code to reflect the .Trim I get ` 1 |  …  Paths\*"  | Where-Object {$_.'(default)'.Trim('"') -ne $null} | Sele …
     |                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.`

Comment: The $q removed all the quotes in the formatting.  However some items had dbl quotes and those items still have there quotes